# How can I implement multiple nameColumns that target the same table?

Tags: ssas

I have two tables. The first one references the second one multiple times.
Some demo data:

```
id      fk1     fk2     fk3
-------------------------------
4009    9419    2282    9005
4057    9419    2112    NULL
5480    NULL    4279    NULL
5989    NULL    1677    NULL
```

The second table contains the names for the foreign keys in table 1

```
id      name
--------------------------------
1677    Bank Account No1
2112    Loyalty Account
2282    Sales Account
4279    Employee Account
9005    Warehouse No1
9419    Sales
```

I have to create a dimension for Table1. The fields fk1, fk2 and fk3 should use the nameColumn attribute, and show the values from table 2.

I tried creating this named query in the Data SourcE View, but if I try to put it into the cube, the deployment breaks without proper error.

```
SELECT [Table1].[id]
    ,fk1
    ,fk2
    ,fk3 
    ,T2_fk1.name as fk1name
    ,T2_fk2.name as fk1name
    ,T2_fk3.name as fk1name
FROM [dbo].[Table1]
left join Table2 as T2_fk1
    on Table2.id = [Table1].fk1
left join Table2 as T2_fk2
    on Table2.id = [Table1].fk2
left join Table2 as T2_fk3
    on Table2.id = [Table1].fk3
```

How can I implement multiple nameColumns that target the same table?

Comment: I always try to avoid NULL values in attribute columns, i. e. I would use something like `coalesce(T2_fk1.name, '<unknown>') as fk1name` etc.

Comment: Are you sure that the reason that "the deployment breaks without proper error" is this specific named query?

Comment: You were right with your first comment. The deployment broke because a NULL value was used as value for nameColumn. You can make an answer and I will acceppt it...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Even if `NULL` values can technically be used in Dimensions in Analysis Services, it is normally a bad idea to do so, as Analysis Services and the relational database have different ideas how they treat them: Analysis Services treats them as empty strings or numerical zeroes, while for the relational database, normally - with the exception of e. g. old versions of Oracle, which treat empty strings as `null` - these are different. Hence when Analysis Services issues a SQL statement containing `DISTINCT` or `GROUP BY`, it can happen that there is more than one row where Analysis Services only expects one, etc.

It is best practice to avoid `null`s in attribute columns, as well as foreign key columns in the star schema. In measure columns, `null`s are fine. Thus, you should change your statement to

```
SELECT [Table1].[id]
    ,coalesce(fk1, -1) as fk1
    ,coalesce(fk2, -1) as fk2
    ,coalesce(fk3, -1) as fk3
    ,coalesce(T2_fk1.name, '<unknown>') as fk1name
    ,coalesce(T2_fk2.name, '<unknown>') as fk1name
    ,coalesce(T2_fk3.name, '<unknown>') as fk1name
FROM [dbo].[Table1]
left join Table2 as T2_fk1
    on Table2.id = [Table1].fk1
left join Table2 as T2_fk2
    on Table2.id = [Table1].fk2
left join Table2 as T2_fk3
    on Table2.id = [Table1].fk3
```

or whatever you chose to replace `null`s with instead of `-1` or `<unknown>`.